# Making a data frame that references my data set

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to make a data frame.

```
df = data_frame(
  data$Name,
  data$classification,
  data$HP,
  data$Weight,
  data$Height,
  data$Att,
  data$Def,
  data$Spe,
  data$Spa,
  data$Spd,
  data$Type_1,
  data$Type_2,
  data$Abilities,
  data$Generation,
  data$Legendary,
  data$Catch_Rate
)
```

but the only way I found for it to work is if I put `data$` before each column. Is there a way to make it without `data$` by making the data some sort of default?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`data_frame()` was deprecated in tibble 1.1.0.
Instead, you may try

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  select(Name, classification, HP, Weight, Height, Att, Def, Spe, Spa, Spd, Type_1, Type_2, Abilities, Generation, Legendary, Catch_Rate) %>%
  tibble()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do

```
data <- data[c("Name", "classification", "HP", "Weight", "Height", "Att", 
               "Def", "Spe", "Spa", "Spd", "Type_1", "Type_2", "Abilities", 
               "Generation", "Legendary", "Catch_Rate")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `names(df)` to change the names of your `df`

```
names(df)<-c("Name", "Classification","HP", "Weight","Height", "Att", "Def","Spe","Spa","Spd","Type_1","Type_2", "Abilities","Generation","Legendary","Catch_Rate")
```